# self.assertRaise not catching TypeError even though it is being raised

Tags: python, unit-testing

i have the following function:

```
def is_complete(grph):
    if not isinstance(grph,graph):
        raise TypeError 
            ...
```

and the following test case for it:

```
def test_is_complete_q4(self):
        g1 = [1]
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, is_complete(g1))
```

I get the following error:
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/Users/.../test_graph_functions.py", line 34, in test_is_complete_q4
    self.assertRaises(TypeError, is_complete(g1))
  File "/Users/.../graph_functions.py", line 6, in is_complete
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

I can clearly see the TypeError being raised so why does my unittest fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the return value of a call to `is_complete` as the second argument to `self.assertRaises`. Instead, you need to pass the function `is_complete` itself as the second argument, with the arguments for `is_complete` as additional arguments to `assertRaises`. (In other words, pass the pieces to `assertRaises`, and let *it* make the actual call.)

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, is_complete, g1)
```

Alternatively, you can use `assertRaises` as a context manager, and call your function in the body of a `with` statement.

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    is_complete(g1)
```